# Character Segmentation with open CV on Captcha Images

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have processed captcha images like the ones seen above, how can I use open cv to separate the characters and save them as individual images? Any suggestions on improving the image processing is also welcome

Comment: Documentation for Google OCR Tesseract can be useful: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality)

Comment: I don't see method to separate every char but if you want to split into 3 parts then you can use white color in original version to detect regions.

Comment: dont quite understand what you mean by split into 3 parts and use white color in original version

Comment: I see 3 yellow regions on image - if you want split image into 3 parts (every yellow region in separated image) then you can use white color between yellow regions to split it.

Comment: the images i show are 3 captchas, each of them converted to their own black and white versions.

Comment: it looks like one image with 3 sections :)